# How to send an image stored as BLOB to front end from a restful web service?

Tags: json, spring, image, rest, spring-boot

I have a web service right now which is taking an image from the front end and saving it as BLOB in database. I want to fetch the image from the database and send it back to the front end restfully and display the image there.

How do I go about it ?

**This is my Model:**

```
@Entity 
public class Document {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Lob
private byte[] image;

public Document(){}

public Document(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

**This is the Service:**

```
@Service

public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {

private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

@Autowired
public DocumentServiceImpl(DocumentRepository documentRepository) {
    this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
}


@Override
public void saveDocument(Document document) {
    documentRepository.save(document);
}

@Override
public List<Document> getAllDocuments() {
    return documentRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public void deleteDocument(Integer id) {
    documentRepository.delete(id);
}

@Override
public Document getById(Integer id) {
    return documentRepository.getOne(id);
}
```

**This is the controller**:

```
@Controller
public class DocumentController {

private DocumentService documentService;

public DocumentController(DocumentService documentService) {
    this.documentService = documentService;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> saveNewDocument(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please select a file to upload.");
    }

    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setImage(bytes);
        documentService.saveDocument(document);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("File uploaded succesfully");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("File could not be uploaded");
    }


}
```

**Front end:**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>FileUpload</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do smth like this:

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/image")
public class ImageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getImage(@PathVariable("imageId") Long imageId) {
        Document doc = documentService.findOne(imageId);
        if (doc == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "image/*").body(doc.getImage());
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<img src="/image/{imageId}">
...
```